# ¿Porque nunca me carga el git push?

Tags: git, git-push

[image: Codigo]
Adjunto el código, literalmente se queda así por horas y no se sube nada

Comment: Ese remoto es accesible a traves de la red? Si es asi, al hacer push, tienes trafico hacvia el servidor? Bienvenido a SO!

Comment: Sí, es un repositorio en Github

Comment: Te toca verificar la segunda parte de mi comentario entonces (idealmente, con un sniffer).

Comment: Podrias hacer pruebas bien sencillas, incluso: hacerle ping al servidor.... tratar de conectarte con ssh al servidor. Si esas dos pruebas son exitosas, entonces podriamos ver si hay un problema en git.

Comment: Puedes hacer `git fetch origin`?

Comment: soy nuevo con git, hice `git fetch origin` y sí me cargo

Comment: Si pudiste hacer fetch, no se me ocurre una razón poor la cual fallaría un push.

Comment: Intenta ejecutar el comando asi:  `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=1 GCM_TRACE=1 git push origin Fernando` y nos cuentas que sale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuve el mismo problema. Lo que hice y me funciono fue lo siguiente:

1. ve al administrador de tareas, encontraras un programa denominado *credentrial manager core*. Le pones ckick derecho finalizar tarea. Esperas un momento y te aparecera un cuadrito de login que te pedira tu usuario de GitHub, pones tu usuario y luego pones ok,en seguida te pedira tu contraseña. Y eso es todo. Regresas a tu terminal para realizar tu git push y te debe funcionar.